# "Your phone is too slow" Message that have been shown after every few minutes

Tags: applications

An app has been shared from my friends phone. But when I try to open that app, I'm getting "Your phone is too slow" message. After uninstalled the app, I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the message, and mention the Android version and device name?

Comment: i am using lenovo A7000 mobile with android5.0

Comment: Honestly, android doesn't have any inbuilt way to give out warnings like that. It does have code to switch to alternate methods if the device's specs aren't enough, or it may hang/lag, but it never gives out any such message. So a high chance is that the message is a spam/advertisement. Can you post the screenshot of the message here? It would help knowing the possibilities (since android system toasts and messages look quite different than advertisements etc, mostly). Plus your phone is good enough, not that slow. So such possibilities are even high.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop an application that use so much memory in the background by doing :
1. Go to your phone Settings
2. Select "Apps"
3. Select the tab "Running"
4. Click on an app that you don't use it or have a high memory consumption
5. Click stop
Hope this works.
If this method doesn't work, you **might** need to factory reset your phone.
**That's my suggestion**

Comment: Are you sure it's a genuine message and not an Advertisement by a rogue app?

Comment: thats what i am not able to confirm

Comment: Is there an app called "Mobogenie" in your phone? You need to un-install it. It gives you some pop-up add such as what you having now.